# Apache ErrorDocument 429 HTTP_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS unsupported

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, errordocument

I'm trying setup the HTTP_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS status code (429) for Apache, but it doens't seems to be supported by my version of Apache when i run a configtest:

```
Unsupported HTTP response code 429
```

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04.2
- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Try using a current version of Apache.

Comment: Alright. Apache/2.4.7 seems to be accepting the config. Thank you.